# Facebook open graph on a domain with url masking and wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, cloaking

im using wordpress on my web site and im having problems posting articles on facebook.
for every article i post i always get the same og title and og url. this is cleary a url masking issue as my meta tags cannot change even if i settled them on wordpress header.php.

here is the website.

http://carnagenews.com/

anyone can help me?

basically i want dynamic og title/url/description/image avoiding that the url cloaking always output the same meta tag

thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

There is couple of issue with your site:

- Your site on `http://carnagenews.com/` is just a top-level frame wrapping `http://carnageweb.altervista.org/` which Facebook will not follow with linter and will not populate your OpenGraph data with correct details until OpenGraph meta exists at the URL specified by `og:url` meta tag.
- Your real pages result in 404 response code for Facebook Linter ([check for yourself using Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://carnageweb.altervista.org/true-blood-stagione-5-il-ritorno-dei-sexy-vampiri/)).

Comment: thanks juicy, i want to mantain the frame in order to mask the url domain, how can i solve the issue?? should i modify my .htaccess file?

Comment: `.htaccess` wouldn't help here, at least until you going to proxy all your request to real pages (look into both mod_proxy andmod_rewrite `P` flag). The only solution is that URL specified by `og:url` must include OpenGraph tags in page source code, there is no other choice.